# Replacing one of the parameters in the URL having a query string and retaining the other parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to replace a URL parameter value with the Apache rewrite.

```
RewriteCond ℅{QUERY_STRING} market=value [NC]
RewriteRule ^/page.html /page.html?market=new-value [R=301,L,NC]
```

The URL pattern is `https://example.com/page.html?market=value&store=value`

I need to replace only the `market` parameter value and retain the `store` parameter as is.

Comment: Where are you using this rule?

Comment: Im using this in Htaccess file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/page.html /page.html?market=new-value [R=301,L,NC]
> ```

Note that when used in `.htaccess`, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash, so the regex `^/page.html` used above will never match in this context.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?(market=)value(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^/?page\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2new-value%3 [NE,R=301,L]
```

This looks for the `market=value` URL parameter name/value pair anywhere in the query string. We capture the parts of the query string that surround the `market` URL parameter *value* (including the parameter name itself). These are saved in the following backreferences:

- `%1` / pattern `(.*&)?` - the part of the query string *before* the `market` URL parameter (if any). This includes the `&` delimiter before the `market` URL parameter name.
- `%2` / pattern `(market=)` - captures the literal text `market=`. This must match to be successful. This simply saves repetition later.
- `%3` / pattern `(&.*)?` - the part of the query string *after* the `market` URL parameter (if any). This includes the `&` delimiter after the `market` URL parameter value.

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable in the *substitution* string contains the full root-relative URL-path. We follow this with the query string that we rebuild using the backreferences as explained above, injecting `new-value` as the value of the `market` URL param (replacing the `value` this URL parameter had originally).

The `NE` (`noescape`) flag is required to prevent the `&` (URL param delimiter) being URL-encoded in the response.

Note that I removed the `NC` (`nocase`) flag from both the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives. URL parameter names are not normally case-insensitive and this rule (as written) will preserve the case used in the request.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues, even if you change this to a permanent redirect later. And you will need to clear your browser cache before testing, since the earlier 301 (permanent) redirect will have been cached by the browser.